# optashift-employee-rostering build fails on openshift

Tags: gwt, openshift, optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

Trying to build the [optashift-employee-rostering project](https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering#locally-with-openshift-origin)

I followed the instructions [in the readme file](https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering#locally-with-openshift-origin) to build the app from [this repo](https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering), but it fails every time. When I try it locally on my Windows 10 with Docker and the "oc.exe" tool, it simply hangs and the oc fails to open even the openshift local console (the one on localhost).

I've created an account on openshift (Starter: US East (Virginia) For individual learning and experimenting.)
When I do it in openshift online, it fails the build but doesn't tell me the reason.
Here are the logs:
http://pasted.co/47eed571

How can I deploy this app to openshift or to some other cloud (Google Cloud/Microsoft Azure etc.)

Comment: It likely ran out of memory on the build. Run ``oc get pods``. Do you see a status message something like OOMKilled for the build pod?

Comment: You can increase memory for the build beyond the 512MB by running ``oc patch bc/yourappname --patch '{"spec":{"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift Online (= free edition) has less than 1GB of RAM for the build pods, which isn't enough to build it (GWT compilations needs more). That leads to error code 137 during GWT compilation.

But OpenShift Online is enough to run it.

Workaround: Build the war locally with `./provision.sh deploy employee-rostering --binary`
as explained [here in the readme](https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering#openshift-online). I hope that GWT and OpenShift play along better in the future.

Comment: That worked! I was able to run the webapp locally after I increased memory limits in Docker settings to maximum (5 GB). I followed [these instructions to deploy Locally with OpenShift Origin](https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering#locally-with-openshift-origin "Locally with OpenShift Origin")

Comment: But where do I run this `provision.sh`? I downloaded this script from the source on GitHub, but if I run it in Windows Command prompt, a window appear for a moment and disappears - that is Git Bash terminal, which says that oc tools need to be installed. I downloaded the tools v3.7.1 for Linux to the same directory as the script, but still get the same behavior.

Comment: Now, I installed “Bash on Ubuntu on Windows”, ran the `provision.sh` script there (but I had to swap the 2nd line with the 1st line in the script, [otherwise it fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45784) with a `Syntax error: “(” unexpected`). But now it fails with `mvn: command not found` error. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: I think I just fixed that, presuming you have maven installed (in your .bashrc is fine now)